# magento2 checkout shipping methods render

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-methods

Please, help me.
Magento 2 checkout page rerender shipping methods when i change country in "Shipping address". I've added one more select field with shippment type ( courier, pickup or both of it) and now i need to load shipping methods, that have selected type.
[image: Checkout page with my field]
I'l gived to shippment method new attribute via xml:

```
        <field id="shippingtypes" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="90" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Shipping types</label>
            <source_model>MyVendor\MyModule\Model\Config\Source\AllShippingTypes</source_model>
        </field>
```

[image: My Shipping method with additionsl field "Shipping Types"]

So question is how to load only shipping methods, that have same shipping type attribute, that selected by user and rerender it, when it change like with countries?

Comment: This will be unique `shippingtypes`. U have to apply/choose different name